# PHP Validation Input Form

Tags: php, validation, function-parameter

I'm making an input form, and I'm currently in the process of validating the code. I run into this validation code from a blog and it seems pretty neat. Does anybody know how to implement this code into a form? Any help is appreciated.

```
function field_validator($field_descr, $field_data, $field_type, $min_length="", $max_length="", $field_required=1) {
    # array for storing error messages
    global $messages;

    # first, if no data and field is not required, just return now:
    if(!$field_data && !$field_required){ return; }
     # initialize a flag variable - used to flag whether data is valid or not
    $field_ok=false;
     # this is the regexp for email validation:
    $email_regexp="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|"
    $email_regexp.="(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$";
     # a hash array of "types of data" pointing to "regexps" used to validate the data:
    $data_types=array(
        "email"=>$email_regexp,
        "digit"=>"^[0-9]$",
        "number"=>"^[0-9]+$",
        "alpha"=>"^[a-zA-Z]+$",
        "alpha_space"=>"^[a-zA-Z ]+$",
        "alphanumeric"=>"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$",
        "alphanumeric_space"=>"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$",
        "string"=>""
    );

    # check for required fields
    if ($field_required && empty($field_data)) {
        $messages[] = "$field_descr is a required field.";
        return;
    }

    # if field type is a string, no need to check regexp:
    if ($field_type == "string") {
        $field_ok = true;
    } else {
        # Check the field data against the regexp pattern:
        $field_ok = ereg($data_types[$field_type], $field_data);
    }

    # if field data is bad, add message:
    if (!$field_ok) {
        $messages[] = "Please enter a valid $field_descr.";
        return;
    }

    # field data min length checking:
    if ($field_ok && $min_length) {
        if (strlen($field_data) $max_length) {
            $messages[] = "$field_descr is invalid, it should be less than $max_length characters.";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you write this? If not, the code gives errors. Why not create your own function?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Im fitting the code into my form as we speak.

Answer (score 2):

try to use Jquery...

```
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" method="post" action="insert.php">
    <label for="Fname">Name </label>
    <input id="_Fname" name= "Fname" value=''/>
    <input id="_Lname" name= "Lname" value=''/>
    <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And js file would be something like this..

```
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#regForm").validate({
        rules: {
                    Fname:{ 
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
            },
                    Lname:{ 
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
            },
            },
            messages: {
                    Fname:{ 
            required: "Please enter your firstname",
            minlength: "name must b 3 character long"
            },
                    Lname: { 
            required: "Please enter your lastname",
            minlength: "name must b 3 character long"
            }
    }
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
     });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: You should at least qualify your answer by telling the OP that front end validation is NOT secure validation.  All it provides is some convenience that prevents unnecessary form submission if data is invalid/incomplete/incorrect. If you require your data to be securely validated before it enters the database or is being used by the back end, you MUST validate it on the server.